# Is there a meteor package to get a state if I enter a city or lat long coord?

Tags: meteor, state, geo, country, city

I have searched stackexchange but can't find a module that creates the relationship between city, state and country.

If this doesn't exist then could you point me to a scheme db to recreate this. I also didn't want to fill out the db with this region hierarchy but if it doesn't exist then I'll use the db scheme you can recommend.

Thank you,

V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly in meteor, but you can use https://atmospherejs.com/dburles/google-maps, to inject google maps api in meteor, and then you can use the geoCoder to get the text location from the latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an existing package afaik but you can use (for example), the [google maps geocoding api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) directly from Meteor.